# WooCommerce: Override the title set to the browsers tab in my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to change the title set in the browsers tab when visiting the `My Account` page in WooCommerce.

When I go for example to the `Orders` page the tab is still named `My Account` and this is not so nice. It should always has the name of the endpoint / `account_menu_items`. I've tried this here but this changes only the title on the menu content at the top left:

```
/**
 * Change title for menu items
 */
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_account_endpoint_titles' );
function custom_account_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( in_the_loop() && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['orders'] ) ) {
        return 'Orders';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which WordPress theme are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Me I'm using Divi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the filter and the way to change it:

```
/**
 * Override woocommerce account endpoint titles in the browser tab
 */
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'woocommerce_endpoint_titles' );
function woocommerce_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
    $sep       = ' – ';
    $sitetitle = get_bloginfo();

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ) {
        $title = 'Bestellungen' . $sep . $sitetitle;
    } elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $title = 'Bestellung' . $sep . $sitetitle;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

If you created your own endpoints in WooCommerce you can use this filter too but you need to register your custom endpoints first. You can do it this way:

```
/**
 * Add custom menu items to wc query vars so that we can use is_wc_endpoint_url()
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'add_items_to_query_vars' );
function add_items_to_query_vars( $vars ) {

    foreach ( [ 'custom-endpoint-1', 'custom-endpoint-2' ] as $e ) {
        $vars[ $e ] = $e;
    }

    return $vars;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `pre_get_document_title` filter instead as this allows you to modify it before it's rendered.

Note theat the `$title_pieces` is actually an array that looks like

```
array (
  'title' => 'title example',
  'tagline' => 'just another wordpress blog'
}
```

So you need to do it like this

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_account_endpoint_titles' );

function custom_account_endpoint_titles($title_pieces) {

    global $wp_query;

    if ( in_the_loop() && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['orders'] ) ) {

      $title_pieces['title'] = 'Orders';
      //$title_pieces['tagline'] = 'Your tag line'; Set a tag line if you want to

      return $title_pieces;
    }

    return $title_pieces;

}
```

Also, make sure to dump the value of `$wp_query->query_vars['orders']` to ensure its the value you're actually looking for

Comment: Added this but it don't works. Still My Account in the tab :(

Comment: delete the `global $wp_query;`, delete the `if` statement and set `$title = 'test'`. What about then? Make sure to clear cache aswell

Comment: what version of WP are you using?

Comment: Using version 4.9.9 with the Divi Theme and Yoast SEO installed.

Comment: check the `head.php` template file to see if it is using `wp_head()`

Comment: Checked it an it uses wp_head();

Comment: On a fresh WP, I have tested this and it works. Problem for you must be elsewhere

Comment: The problem is likely your `if()` statement logic, check if the condition you passed is actually true